# python : multithreading : self as global variable

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

I have some problems with python's multithreading:
generating a thread, it gets some parameters like the thread name, a counter and such.  In the 'run'-part of the thread it is calling  some sub-functions (and there again sub functions to some depths) However, the self - variable (class) seems NOT to exist in the sub functions : referring to self.name shows up some error (NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
).  Is there any way to get the content of the complete structure in those sub-functions without (!!) parameterizing everything ( this will becoming damned long at depth 4 ...). Hope this short example will explain it better,  in sub1 the second print line tries to access self.counter

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import time

globalVar = 1;

def sub1  ( name ):
  global globalVar ;

  print str(globalVar) + " in der 1. subfunktion von " +str(name)
  print "teste self"  + str(self.counter) + " - " + globalVar + " " +str(name) ;
  globalVar += 1 ;
  time.sleep(1);
  sub2 (name) ;
  return None ;


class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name + " mit zaehler " + str(self.counter)
        sub1 (self.name);

threadLock = threading.Lock()
threads = [] ;

# Create new threads
count =0;
while count < 10 :
        count += 1;
        threadX = myThread(count, "Thread-" + str(count), count)
        threadX.start()
        threads.append(threadX)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: have you tried passing the whole object `self` instead of just one property `self.name` in the thread run? `sub1(self)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you didn't simply pass the `self` instead of `name`?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading
import time

globalVar = 1;

def sub1  ( self ):
  global globalVar ;

  print str(globalVar) + " in der 1. subfunktion von " +str(self.name)
  print "teste self"  + str(self.counter) + " - " + str(globalVar) + " " +str(self.name) ;
  globalVar += 1 ;
  time.sleep(1);
  sub2 (self.name) ;
  return None ;


class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name + " mit zaehler " + str(self.counter)
        sub1 (self);

threadLock = threading.Lock()
threads = [] ;

# Create new threads
count =0;
while count < 10 :
        count += 1;
        threadX = myThread(count, "Thread-" + str(count), count)
        threadX.start()
        threads.append(threadX)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
print "Exiting Main Thread"
```

*Due to `int` can't concatenate with `string`, I replaced `globalVar` with `str(globalVar)` in `sub1` method.*

Works as below:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Starting Thread-1 mit zaehler 1
1 in der 1. subfunktion von Thread-1
teste self1 - 1 Thread-1
Starting Thread-2 mit zaehler 2
2 in der 1. subfunktion von Thread-2
teste self2 - 2 Thread-2Starting Thread-3 mit zaehler 3
 Starting Thread-5 mit zaehler 5
Starting Thread-6 mit zaehler 6Starting Thread-7 mit zaehler 7Starting Thread-4 mit zaehler 4Starting Thread-8 mit zaehler 8Starting Thread-9 mit zaehler 9
 3 in der 1. subfunktion von Thread-3




3 in der 1. subfunktion von Thread-5Starting Thread-10 mit zaehler 10
3 in der 1. subfunktion von Thread-63 in der 1. subfunktion von Thread-73 in der 1. subfunktion von Thread-9
teste self3 - 3 Thread-3
3 in der 1. subfunktion von Thread-43 in der 1. subfunktion von Thread-8


teste self5 - 3 Thread-5
teste self7 - 3 Thread-7

3 in der 1. subfunktion von Thread-10teste self6 - 3 Thread-6teste self9 - 3 Thread-9
teste self4 - 4 Thread-4
teste self8 - 5 Thread-8

teste self10 - 6 Thread-10


//+ A bunch of Sub2 is not defined errors ...
```

Answer (score 0):

sub1 is not a "sub function". Python has "nested" functions but this is not an example of it. "sub1" has a completely different scope and can not see any variables under your class.

If you want access to the class instance (self) variables and methods, you should pass "self" as the argument to sub1, not self.name which is only the string "Thread-#"

```
def sub1(thread_instance):
    print thread_instance.name, thread_instance.threadID
```

Then in your "run" method, call it with self:

```
def run(self):
    sub1(self)
```

Do not use global variables with threading to store objects from threads as they this will definitely cause headaches when multiple threads read and write to this variable.

Also, what is the point of having a threadID and counter argument to your class if they are both one and the same? Also your code example is incomplete and missing code to make it hard to understand what you are trying to achieve with this and what you are attempted to do.

Another thing, you don't need semi-colons after each line, this isn't C. I would focus on understanding the Python language a little more first and get some basics first before using threading.